# To use ngIf on @Output value

Tags: angular

Child.html

```
   <div>
     <md-select id="vendorVariable" class="vm-
        select-wrap" 
        (ngModelChange)="vendorUpdate($event)"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedVendor" 
        placeholder="AWS" 
        name="vendorVariable">
      <md-option  *ngFor="let vendor of vendors" 
         [value]="vendor.small">
         {{vendor.caps}}
      </md-option>
     </md-select>
    </div>
```

Child.ts

```
  vendors: any = [
     {caps: "AWS", small: "aws"},
     {caps: "AZURE", small: "azure"}
  ];

  @Output() selectedCloudEnv = new 
  EventEmitter();
  --------
  function
  --------
  vendorUpdate(value){
  console.log(value);
  this.selectedCloudEnv.emit(value);    

  }
```

Parent.html

```
<div class="bundle-tab-container pad-rlt" 
 *ngIf="!azureSelected">
   <child 
  (selectedCloudEnv)="selectedCloudEnv($event)">
   </child>
</div>
<div class="bundle-tab-container pad-rlt" 
  *ngIf="azureSelected">
  <cloud-azure></cloud-azure>
</div>
```

parent.ts

```
 azureSelected: Boolean = false;
  selectedCloudEnv(value){
  console.log("inside parent");
  console.log("parent"+value);
  if(value === "azure"){
     this.azureSelected = true;
  }
  else{
     this.azureSelected=false;
  }
```

I am passing the value from child to parent and then depending upon subsequent value my objective is to hide the child template and show the second template "cloud-azure" using `ngIf = azureSelected` (true or false).I am getting the value in parent but ngIf is not working.

The error on console is

```
        `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elementRef' of undefined
         at MdTabHeader.webpackJsonp.../../../material/tabs/tab-
         header.js.MdTabHeader._alignInkBarToSelectedTab 
         (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:137599:64)
         at http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:137387:23
         at
         ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../..
         /zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask 
         (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:51598:31)
          at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask 
         (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:51397:47)
          at ZoneTask.invoke 
          (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:51651:38)
         at data.args.(anonymous function) 
         (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:52812:29) `
```

And the code is

```
                            `<md-tab>
                            <template md-tab-label>
                            VIRTUAL MACHINES
                            </template>
                             <div class="bundle-tab-container pad-rlt" 
                           *ngIf="!azureSelected">
                            <cloud-services 
                            (selectedCloudEnv)="selectedCloudEnv($event)">
                            </cloud-
                            services>
                             </div>
                            <div class="bundle-tab-container pad-rlt" 
                            *ngIf="azureSelected">
                             <cloud-azure></cloud-azure>
                            </div>
                            </md-tab> `
```

Comment: Thanks Hareesh for the edit , could you please help with my approach , the ngIf :)Actually I am trying to hide the child template from which I am getting the output value

Comment: can you create a plunker for the same

Comment: @RahulSingh I have created a plunker and it's working for me... [see here](https://plnkr.co/edit/wwnjMnZ6LsdHmUFxbRW1?p=preview). I copied and pasted his code almost exactly so I'm not sure what the issue is

Comment: @0mpurdy it should .

Comment: I just created a plunk to check this issue in a demo page it works there is something else that is bugging you . [plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/8NNqKXAORrmTn5DFICEw?p=preview) .make the count 5 to see the div in the plunk

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue. Angular 4.0.0, CDK/Material 2.0.0-beta.8, exact same component setup. Do you see any errors on the console? Did you include `import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';` required by Material? Did you install de CDK as well?

Comment: Thanks for the help I am using Angular2 "@angular/core": "^2.4.3", and Material "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.1",

Comment: Rahul Singh and BrunoLM but I am not able to run

Comment: 0mpurdy , @RahulSingh , Sorry for the delay,the above code is correct in angular context,actually I have figured out the issue ,the issue is because my code tries to calculate the width and height of the "div" on which I have placed *ngIf so is there any lifecycle hook to rescue, these kind of situation, I have given hidden attribute and now it is working but I know using hidden attribute is not advisable